# How to add .pdf extension when sending an attachment from Android?

Tags: android, email, attachment

I am trying to send a pdf as an attachment from Android. Here is the code:

```
String[] mailto = {"me@gmail.com"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mywebsite.sendemail/raw/mypdf");

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Body");
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
```

Now this works but the problem is that the attachment is called mypdf instead of mypdf.pdf. I cannot figure out how to send it with it's extension... That's what I need help with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unconvinced what you want will be possible, since you are pulling the PDF from a resource. If you copy the PDF to a local file (with the correct extension) and send that, you should get the extension in the resulting message. But straight out of the resource...I suspect there's no way to add the extension.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have been able to solve the problem by copying the file to the SDCard and then using Uri.fromFile. I don't like the solution because if the SDCard is missing or busy, it won't work. I put a copy of the pdf in the /assets directory but have not been able to get it to work with Uri.fromFile or Uri.parse. Not sure why...

Comment: Hmmm...`file:///android_asset/mypdf.pdf` might work. I have only used that syntax for things in my own app, though, not for passing to another app.

Comment: I tried 18 different permutations of fromFile and parse including using android_asset as you suggested. I pretty well have convinced myself that it must be read from the SDCard... Which is unfortunate. That is something that could really be improved in Android... Here is the uri I ended up using to read from the card:     Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mypdf.pdf"));

Answer (score 1):

When ever I attempt to use the .putExtra methodology it always crashes my application with a "Force Close" message.  If I use something like:
   String mtUri = "mailto:someone@gmail.com?subject=Some Subject&body=Some text&";
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(mtUri));
   startActivity(intent);

It seems to work fine.  I do still have the problem of attaching a file and could use some help figurint out the "attachment=file:///..." syntax.

Thanks,